# letternapped! Alien invasion or random glitch?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

[image]

(*[Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8q1c.png)*)

There's some serious screwiness with the SU/MSU websites. Lots of letters seem missing - even on this, only the E in the submit button seems visible.

I'm running Google Chrome Canary 16.0.883.0.

Comment: the current version of Chrome is THIRTEEN, fyi. We don't support beta browsers...

Comment: god damn it, the VERSION CHANGED AFTER I CHECKED IT. Now it's Chrome FOURTEEN.... FUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUuuuuuuu

Comment: hm. And it works perfectly on another box with an updated canary build. I suppose the answer is 'random glitch' and ending up looking silly.

Comment: @Jeff: and like that, you magically started supporting Chrome 14. You need to start keeping track of how often this happens... it's definitely been more than once.

Answer (score 3):

Looks fine to me... what happens if you refresh or use a different browser?

[image]

Comment: looks fine on FF apparently, hm, might be a canary glitch

Comment: That's what, a nightly build or similar? Stack Exchange only supports the current and previous version of major browsers. Given how "cutting edge" that build is, it's certainly a browser bug, not a problem with the SE engine.

Comment: nightly. Sort of forgot about that- i routinely surf SU on shared boxen at home with it, and this is the first time it happened...